# Homology group of $X$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

Can I say that the homology group  $ H_n(X)$  it gives us the information of how many holes the topological space $X$ has ? And for an example to say that the $H_n(\bigtriangleup^{n} )=0$ because n simplexis dont have holes and compare it to $H_n(X )=1$ where $X$ here is a torus which has one hole? Meaning if $ H_n(X)\neq H_n(Y) $ then $X$ can't be isomorphic to $Y$ ?

Answer (score 3):

The latter *is* true: if $X$ is homeomorphic to $Y$, then $H_n(X)$ is isomorphic to $H_n(Y)$ for all $n$, because the construction of the $H_n$ is a *functor*, so transforms continuous functions to morphisms (of groups) in a way that preserves composition and identities. This is why by the contrapositive we can say that $H_n(X) \neq H_n(Y)$ for some $n$ implies $X \not\simeq Y$, and this is one of the applications of homology (and of other functors like homotopy groups and cohomology etc.).

What $H_n(X)$ "measures" exactly is hard to say, others might have more to say on that. I've always found it somewhat "magical" (you take a large quotient of maps and voila we get $\Bbb Z$...), though it is inspired by simplicial subdivisions in of surfaces in  $\Bbb R^n$ etc.

Comment: That was helpful Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Intuitively, you can think of $H_n(X)$ as measuring the *$n$-dimensional holes* of your space $X$. This observation is motivated by the homology groups we encounter on simple spaces such as spheres and tori etc.

Saying $H_n(\Delta^n) = 0 $ would mean there are *no $n$-dimensional holes* in your space $\Delta^n$. If $\Delta^n$ is supposed to be the $n$-simplex, note that $\Delta^n$ is homeomorphic to the $n$-dimensional ball $D^n$ which is homotopy equivalent to a point $*$ and homotopy equivalent spaces have isomorphic homology groups, therefore

$$H_n(\Delta^n) \cong H_n(D^n) \cong H_n(*) = 0\ \ \text{for}\ \ n > 0$$

A bit more algebraic background: What homology does actually measure is the failure of exactness of a given chain complex $(C_*,\partial_*)$:

$$\cdots \to C_n \xrightarrow{\partial_n}  C_{n-1} \xrightarrow{\partial_{n-1}} C_{n-2} \xrightarrow{\partial_{n-2}}  \cdots $$

Usually one consideres the chain complex of the (free abelian) chain groups $C_k(X)$ that are generated by the (singular) $k$-chains in $X$.

Now by definition, the $n$th homology group $H_n(X)$ is defined as the quotient $$H_n(X) := \ker \partial_{n}/\operatorname{im}\partial_{n+1}$$

Therefore, the "bigger" the homology group $H_n(X)$, the further your chain complex is away from being exact at $C_n(X)$, the "smaller" $H_n(X)$, the closer you are to exactness at $C_n(X)$. Consequently, if $H_n(X) = 0$, your chain complex is exact at degree $n$, i.e.

$$\ker \partial_{n} = \operatorname{im}\partial_{n+1}.$$

That's what homology groups measure *algebraically*.